# Geometry and fncychap packages create an ugly header - How do I correct that?

Tags: formatting, geometry, fncychap

I am trying to use the `geometry` package for a `oneside` layout.

However it apparently does something unpleasant with my headers. The bottom right part has a rectangle cut out. Without the binding offset, it looks all good.

```
\documentclass[a4paper, oneside, 11pt]{report}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[Bjornstrup]{fncychap}
\usepackage[bindingoffset = 1 cm]{geometry}


%"Bugfix" for fncychap:
%Without this code there will be an overfull hbox by 10pt on every chapter
%I don't remember where I found this, but it seems to be unrelated to 
%the problem sice the header looks the same when commented out.     
%--------------------------------------------------------------------------

\makeatletter
  \renewcommand{\DOCH}{%
    \settowidth{\py}{\CNoV\thechapter}%
    \addtolength{\py}{-10pt}%     % Amount of space by which the
                                  % number is shifted right
    \fboxsep=0pt%
    \colorbox[gray]{.85}{\rule{0pt}{40pt}\parbox[b]{\textwidth}{\hfill}}%
\kern-\myhi
    \kern-\py\raise20pt%
    \hbox{\color[gray]{.5}\CNoV\thechapter}%
\kern-\myhi
\\%
}

%-------------------------------------------------

\begin{document}

\chapter{Diskussion}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam
nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam 
erat, sed diam voluptua. 

\end{document}
```

Also I would want the chapter title in the header to be centered and larger. How do I do that?

The current result:

[image]

The anticipated result would look more like that:

[image]

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

Well, in chapter *3.7 The chapter Bjornstrup* in the documentation of package `fncychap` (open it with `texdoc fncychap`)  you can find the command to get the title centered and bigger, for example with the command

```
\ChTitleVar{\Huge\sffamily\bfseries\centering}
```

If you change the order of calling the packages (package `geometry` first) as shown in my following MWE your *rectangle cut out* vanished.

The MWE (please see I commented out command `\makeatletter`, because it is not needed and has not been closed by `\makeatother`)

```
\documentclass[a4paper, oneside, 11pt]{report}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

%\usepackage[Bjornstrup]{fncychap} % <==================================
\usepackage[% 
  bindingoffset=1cm,
  showframe
]{geometry}

\usepackage[Bjornstrup]{fncychap} % <===================================
\ChTitleVar{\Huge\sffamily\bfseries\centering} % <======================


%"Bugfix" for fncychap:
%Without this code there will be an overfull hbox by 10pt on every chapter
%I don't remember where I found this, but it seems to be unrelated to 
%the problem sice the header looks the same when commented out.     
%--------------------------------------------------------------------------

%\makeatletter
  \renewcommand{\DOCH}{%
    \settowidth{\py}{\CNoV\thechapter}%
    \addtolength{\py}{-10pt}%     % Amount of space by which the
                                  % number is shifted right
    \fboxsep=0pt%
    \colorbox[gray]{.85}{\rule{0pt}{40pt}\parbox[b]{\textwidth}{\hfill}}%
\kern-\myhi
    \kern-\py\raise20pt%
    \hbox{\color[gray]{.5}\CNoV\thechapter}%
\kern-\myhi
\\%
}

%-------------------------------------------------

\begin{document}

\chapter{Diskussion}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam
nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam 
erat, sed diam voluptua. 

\end{document}
```

compiles without errors to

[image]